# Do old Facebook offline_access tokens keep working with offline_access deprecated?

Tags: facebook, deprecated, access-token

I have stored access tokens with offline_access from users of my application. I prepared it to get and extend tokens for 60 days to have my app working with offline_access deprecation. But I need to know what happens with the old tokens.

When offline_access deprecation is enabled, do old stored tokens expire after two hours, 60 days or never expire (until user deauthorizes app, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation covering `offline_access` permission removal](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) `access_token` for users who granted you `offline_access` permission will remains the same as before:

> **If you have been using offline_access**
>
> For those developers who were asking for the offline_access permissions and for those users that granted that permission, **existing access_tokens will continue to have no expiration time**.
>
> For any user that has to login or re-login to your app, they will no longer see the permission for offline_access in the Auth Dialog (because the migration is enabled). **Your app should continue to function as before even without getting the offline_access**, but you should consider using the new endpoint to extend the expiration time of existing access_tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Juicy Scripters answer seems to be no longer valid! The current version of the documentation for [Removal of offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) states:

> Once the migration has been enabled, for those developers who were asking for the offline_access permission and for those users that granted that permission, existing access_tokens will continue to work. However, the **next time that access_token is used** by your app to GET OR POST data from/to Facebook, **its expiration time will automatically be reset from infinite expiration to a finite**, but long expiration. [this will be 60 days]

Make sure your application can handle expiring access_tokens!
Check the roadmap for changes - it seems to be a living document!

Update: It's definitively a living document - from yesterday to today a fifth scenario about Page Access Tokens was added and there's also a small last updated info at the bottom of the page. (btw a changelog and diff would be a really nice addition for these types of documentation)